# Swift 3 - Pass struct by reference via UnsafeMutableRawPointer?

Tags: swift, swift3, pass-by-reference, core-audio, unsafemutablepointer

In the `Core Audio`-Framework user data can be passed into callbacks via an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`. I was wondering how to pass a struct *by reference* via this `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`. Changes made inside the callback should be reflected outside the callback.

I set up a playground to test this:

```
struct TestStruct {
    var prop1: UInt32
    var prop2: Float64
    var prop3: Bool
}

func printTestStruct(prefix: String, data: TestStruct) {
    print("\(prefix): prop1: \(data.prop1), prop2: \(data.prop2), prop3: \(data.prop3)")
}

func testUnsafeMutablePointer(data: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    var testStructInFunc = data!.load(as: TestStruct.self)

    printTestStruct(prefix: "In func (pre change)", data: testStructInFunc)

    testStructInFunc.prop1 = 24
    testStructInFunc.prop2 = 1.2
    testStructInFunc.prop3 = false

    printTestStruct(prefix: "In func (post change)", data: testStructInFunc)
}

var testStruct: TestStruct = TestStruct(prop1: 12, prop2: 2.4, prop3: true)

printTestStruct(prefix: "Before call", data: testStruct)

testUnsafeMutablePointer(data: &testStruct)

printTestStruct(prefix: "After call", data: testStruct)
```

Sadly it seems like any changes to `testStruct` made inside the `testUnsafeMutablePointer` function are lost after the function call.

I was thinking, that the `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` behaves like a pass by reference here? What am I missing out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function copies the data into a local struct, but does not
copy the modified data back. So this would be a possible
solution in your special case:

```
func testUnsafeMutablePointer(data: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    var testStructInFunc = data!.load(as: TestStruct.self)

    testStructInFunc.prop1 = 24
    testStructInFunc.prop2 = 1.2
    testStructInFunc.prop3 = false

    data!.storeBytes(of: testStructInFunc, as: TestStruct.self)
}
```

But note that this works only if the struct contains only "simple"
values likes integers and floating point values. "Complex" types
like arrays or strings contain opaque pointers to the actual storage
and cannot be simply copied like this.

Another option is to modify the pointed-to struct like this:

```
func testUnsafeMutablePointer(data: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    let testStructPtr = data!.assumingMemoryBound(to: TestStruct.self)

    testStructPtr.pointee.prop1 = 24
    testStructPtr.pointee.prop2 = 1.2
    testStructPtr.pointee.prop3 = false
}
```

Both solutions assume that the struct still exists when the callback
is called, since passing a pointer around does not ensure the
lifetime of the pointed-to struct.

As an alternative, consider to use an instance of a `class` instead.
Passing retained or unretained pointers to the instance allows to control
the lifetime of the object while the callback is "active", compare
[How to cast self to UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> type in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift).

Comment: Thank you really much! This definitely clears things up for me. What would be the most _Swifty_ solution here (I assume using `class`, but I'm pretty new to __Swift__)?

Comment: @Herickson: That is difficult to tell without having more context. You are interacting with C APIs, so there is no pure Swift anyway.